Langchain HuggingFace embeddings no longer loading for Llama-Index?
The following code worked about a week ago:
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="WhereIsAI/UAE-Large-V1"))

Previously, the embed_model = ... line takes only a few seconds to execute. However, now when I try to run it, it seems to be running indefinitely without an error/warning message, and it does not execute properly.
Has anyone else come across this issue?

have you updated langchain recently? The documentation suggests importing HuggingFaceEmbeddings from
the langchain_community package.

@eventHandler Thanks for the tip. I updated langchain and imported HuggingFaceEmbeddings from langchain_community according to the documentation. However, the issue still persists.

I haven't done any test, but there is a parameter in the embeddings to show a progress bar. I'm wondering if you are having network issues to download the model. The size is 1.4GB.
